# Get request.session from a class-based generic view

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to get `request.session` from inside a class-based view?

For instance, I have

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class CreateProfileView(FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # --> would like to save form contents to session here

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The only thing I can think of would be override `as_view` by adding

```
def as_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.session = request.session
    super(CreateProfileView, self).as_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

to the class. But that seems ugly. Is there another way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have access to `self.request` from anywhere within the class (and therefore `self.request.session`)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

> The key part to making this work is that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

Comment: The important part here is "when class-based views are *called*"; i.e., it needs to be done within one of the class's *methods* (e.g., def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)), not inside the class but outside any methods.